# MSSQL recursively select all related rows

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, recursive-query

I've got a hierarchy of definition/field relationships which is spread across 3 tables:

```
CREATE TABLE ProductDefinition
(
  ProductDefinitionId int,
  Name nvarchar(10),
)

CREATE TABLE ProductDefinitionRelation
(
  ProductDefinitionId int,
  ParentProductDefinitionId int
)

CREATE TABLE ProductDefinitionField
(
  ProductDefinitionFieldId int,
  ProductDefinitionId int,
  Name nvarchar(10)
)
```

The idea is that this allows the editor of the CMS to share common properties across objects, saving the administrator administration time.

The structure is from a third party so cannot be changed but I now need to select all the parent properties (n deep) so if you have a Grand Parent > Parent > Child hierarchy, the Child will have all properties defined on the Grand Parent/Parent.

I've got pretty close but the issue comes when the Child doesn't have any properties, it gets filtered out by the INNER JOIN within the CTE.

Does anyone know how I can avoid this Child2 in this example would still need to have all the props of Grand Parent/Parent?

I've setup a Fiddle here: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/08dc3/4 but my code is below:

```
INSERT INTO ProductDefinition
    VALUES (1,'G. Parent'),(2,'Parent'),(3,'Child1'),(4,'Child2'),(5,'Child3');

INSERT INTO ProductDefinitionField
VALUES
  (1,1,'G. Field'),
  (2,2,'P. Field'),
  (3,3,'C. Field'),
  (4,5,'C. Field');

INSERT INTO ProductDefinitionRelation
VALUES (2,1),(3,2),(4,2),(5,2);

WITH Fields
AS
    (
        SELECT
            pd.ProductDefinitionId
          , pd.Name AS [ProductDefinitionName]
          , pdf.ProductDefinitionFieldId
          , pdf.Name AS [ProductDefinitionFieldName]
        FROM
            ProductDefinition pd
                LEFT JOIN ProductDefinitionRelation pdr ON pd.ProductDefinitionId = pdr.ProductDefinitionId
                LEFT JOIN ProductDefinitionField pdf ON pd.ProductDefinitionId = pdf.ProductDefinitionId
        WHERE
            pdr.ProductDefinitionId IS NULL

    UNION ALL

        SELECT
            pd.ProductDefinitionId
          , pd.Name AS [ProductDefinitionName]
          , pdf.ProductDefinitionFieldId
          , pdf.Name AS [ProductDefinitionFieldName]
        FROM
            Fields f
                JOIN ProductDefinitionRelation pdr ON f.ProductDefinitionId = pdr.ParentProductDefinitionId
                JOIN ProductDefinition pd ON pdr.ProductDefinitionId = pd.ProductDefinitionId
                JOIN ProductDefinitionField pdf ON pd.ProductDefinitionId = pdf.ProductDefinitionId

    UNION ALL

        SELECT
            pd.ProductDefinitionId
            , pd.Name AS [ProductDefinitionName]
            , f.ProductDefinitionFieldId
            , f.ProductDefinitionFieldName AS [ProductDefinitionFieldName]
        FROM
            Fields f
                JOIN ProductDefinitionRelation pdr ON f.ProductDefinitionId = pdr.ParentProductDefinitionId
                JOIN ProductDefinition pd ON pdr.ProductDefinitionId = pd.ProductDefinitionId
                JOIN ProductDefinitionField pdf ON pd.ProductDefinitionId = pdf.ProductDefinitionId
)
SELECT DISTINCT
    *
FROM
    Fields
ORDER BY
    ProductDefinitionName
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
WITH FIELDS AS
    (
        SELECT
            pd.ProductDefinitionId
          , pd.ProductDefinitionId [ChildDefinitionID]  
          , pd.Name AS [ProductDefinitionName]
          , pdf.ProductDefinitionFieldId
          , pdf.Name AS [ProductDefinitionFieldName]
        FROM
            ProductDefinition pd
            LEFT JOIN ProductDefinitionField pdf ON pd.ProductDefinitionId = pdf.ProductDefinitionId

    UNION ALL

        SELECT
            f.ProductDefinitionId
          , pd.ProductDefinitionId [ChildDefinitionID]
          , f.ProductDefinitionName AS [ProductDefinitionName]
          , pdf.ProductDefinitionFieldId
          , pdf.Name AS [ProductDefinitionFieldName]
        FROM
            Fields f
                JOIN ProductDefinitionRelation pdr ON f.ChildDefinitionID = pdr.ProductDefinitionId  
                JOIN ProductDefinition pd ON pdr.ParentProductDefinitionId = pd.ProductDefinitionId                              
                JOIN ProductDefinitionField pdf ON pd.ProductDefinitionId = pdf.ProductDefinitionId    
)
SELECT DISTINCT
    *
FROM
    Fields
ORDER BY
    ProductDefinitionName
```

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/89721b/11

Idea:
Use two fields to keep track of recursion:

- `ProductDefinitionId` holds the id the fields finally belong to
- `ChildDefinitionID` holds the id of the child, a parent relation is tested against during recursion; initially this is the childs id

Comment: I tried that, the issue with this however is that you lose all Grandparent/Parent properties on the Child. I have a feeling the solution is along these lines though so I'll keep playing.

Comment: What do you mean by "lose all Grandparent/Parent properties"? If you are executing the query in the fiddle, all properties of the parent/grand parent are there.

Comment: If you compare it to my original you get:
Child1 - C. Field, P. Field and G. Field

Yours just returns
Child1 - C. Field

Comment: Edited code and fiddle to provide correct definition names. Is it that what you want?

Comment: Ah yes, sorry, I didn't spot the issue with the name. Cool cheers.